# Can you identify this time travel story set in Sydney about time travel through a tree?

Tags: story-identification

I seem to remember reading a couple of books where a young girl(?) goes back in time from (then) modern day Sydney to about a hundred years before, using a Morton Bay fig tree as the time travel device! Does anyone else remember it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Riddle of the Trumpalar and Challenge of the Trumpalar by Judy Bernard-Waite.

"When twins Cass and Carl vowed to save an ancient Moreton Bay fig tree from destruction they did not realise it was the beginning of a journey that would take them literally inside the tree and from there back in time to the Sydney of the ..."

Comment: Yes! Wow, what an awesome name that is! I had totally forgotten!

Answer (score 2):

[*Playing Beatie Bow*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_Beatie_Bow)? Never read the book, but they forced me to repeatedly watch the very poor film in school.

Comment: Thank you for answering it, but I don't think that is correct. I remember trying Beatie Bow and not liking the book at all, but I remember liking this book and it's sequels.